# Люцифер чи люципер?

Tags: правопис

Таке містичне слово як *чорт* має багато відповідників — нечиста сила, диявол, дідько. Та нещодавно я почула ще одне — *люципер*. Спочатку подумала, що це помилка. Адже слово люци*ф*ер чула давно, та й [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D1%8E%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80) не знає ніякого люци*п*ера. Але заглянувши в [словник](http://sum.in.ua/s/lucyper)
таки знайшла це слово. То ж як правильно "люци*п*ер" чи люци*ф*ер?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Спочатку коротка відповідь, потім докази.

#### Коротка відповідь

Обидва слова є цілком літературними, ви правильно зазначили, що слово "чорт" має багато відповідників. Користуйтеся тим, яке вам більше подобається, або тим, яке стилістично доцільніше у тій чи іншій ситуації.

#### Докази

Щодо "люцифера" питань у вас, я так розумію, не було, тож докази по "люциперу":

[Словарь української мови: в 4-х тт. / За ред. Б. Грінченка.](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80):

> Люци́пер, ра, м. Люциферъ, дьяволъ. Шевч. 592. Чуб. І. 166. Пойде Ірод
>   сам до аду люциперу на пораду. Чуб. III. 359.

[СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/lucyper):

> ЛУЦИ́ПЕР, ЛЮЦИ́ПЕР, а, чол. Те саме, що біс1. На дітей своїх не глянув
>   Луципер проклятий! (Тарас Шевченко, I, 1951, 366);

[СЛОВНИК УКРАЇНСЬКОЇ МОВИ ONLINE.ТОМИ 1-8. (А-МІШУ́РНИЙ) (або СУМ-20)](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=48836&page=1540):

> ЛУЦИ́ПЕР, ЛЮЦИ́ПЕР, а, ч. 1. (з великої літери). Те саме, що люци́фе́р
>   1. – Що се за гайдамака? – питав зачудуваний Луципер (І. Франко); Та народу юрба, наче глуха, непорушно стояла, Здавалося, їй байдуже, де
>   тут Люципер, а де Христос (Д. Павличко).
>   2. розм. Біс, чорт. – Разом вони робили, то хай би разом i вiдпочивали, – казав дядько i кляв тих луциперів, якi додумалися
>   повтискати в залiзо смерть (М. Стельмах)